# how to get NFS properly working in Debian again

Tags: debian, nfs

There are multiple open bugs about NFS for Debian unstable right now.

One description of the problem says that the breakage is triggered by nfs-kernel-server transition to rpcbind - and rpcbind and portmap cannot bind the same port at the same time. However, rpcbind package does not have an init.d script at all, although it seemed to work on my client when started manually (my server is broken as well, so I didn't check it fully).

However, I do not wish for a manually started service on a server that may be rebooted at any time - and I don't wish for a hacky script written by me or some random guy.

So, I'm looking for the "official" solution fixing NFS usage for Debian that doesn't involve manual hacking. The proper solution will obviously take some time, but a good interim solution what is needed by every Debian NFS user world wide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem solved officially, rpcbind package now contains init script, dependencies changed all around.

Answer (score 1):

There are [workarounds](http://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=562757#75) given in the bug report. The first you dont want (running rpcbind manually). The second - NEEDS_STATD=no and -o nolock - works fine for me here. The other option in the beg report thread is to use nfs4, in which case you can just set NEEDS_STATD=no.

Note, the referenced workrounds mistakenly says "-o lock", which should be "-o nolock".

There is unlikely to be an "official" solution. Just keep an eye on the bug reports to see how people are coping with the issue. Instead of an "official" solution, the problem will likely just be fixed - either by fixing rpc.statd, or adding an init script to rpcbind.

Comment: NEEDS_STATD=no fixes nfs-common init script starting, but when attempting to export the filesystems, mountd fails similarily to statd. Hence I think your suggestions do not work for nfs servers.

And I'd rather avoid nfs4. But, your answer was helpful, nonetheless.